# SQL Server 2016 PolyBase install

Tags: installation, sql-server-2016

I'm trying to install and Run PolyBase in a brand new SQL Server environment - the installation runs fine, but I can't get the PolyBase services to start.

In SQL Server Configuration manager I see the state as 'Change Pending...', and task manager shows the services as 'starting'

If I try to configure PolyBase in SSMS it sits there for a while then bombs out with a null reference exception.

I can kill the processes in task manager but still no dice when I try to restart them - sits there for ages before finally returning 'the request failed or the service did not respond in timely fashion'

This is on a newly provisioned Azure VM, using the Developer version of 2016, so as far as I can tell the environment is completely clean - worth noting that I've tried this on two separate environments with the same result.

I've got plenty of SQL Server experience, but I've never used PolyBase before, so I accept that  I might be missing something, but I would expect a fresh out-of-the-box install of SQL server to at least let me run the services...

Hopefully I'm doing something stupid and one of you can steer me in the right direction. Thanks in advance for any help.

CMR

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PolyBase head nodes are only supported in SQL Server 2016 Enterprise Edition. 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645993.aspx

Comment: Thanks for that - I had incorrectly assumed that the developer licence offered everything the enterprise licence did... I'll be more careful about checking this in future

Answer (score 1):

Try enabling TCP/IP for SQL Server Network (by default only Shared Memory is enabled)

Comment: I propose that this should be the accepted answer. Greg Low blogged about this issue, and resolved it by enabling TCP/IP. http://sqlblog.com/blogs/greg_low/archive/2016/07/06/sql-server-2016-polybase-services-stuck-in-change-pending-state.aspx. Also note that in the official MS Docs, it states that TCP/IP must be enabled. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/polybase/get-started-with-polybase

Answer (score 0):

It might be worth installing Service Pack 1 and trying again, because Polybase is now a Feature in Standard Edition.
 https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/sqlreleaseservices/sql-server-2016-service-pack-1-sp1-released/